# Вопросы по склонению

Tags: склонение

Не могу определиться, как лучше просклонять слова в следующих предложениях...

1. В этом плане стандарты и инструкции и позволяют конструктору не допустить те ошибки, которые уже отмечены и проанализированы техническим сообществом.
2. В этой фразе, конечно, есть правда, однако есть и много конструкторов-ремесленников, не вкладывающих в свои творения желание достичь новых показателей, хотя это больше относится к типам личностей и вообще свойственно людям.

Почему-то хочется написать "не допустить тех ошибок" и "не вкладывающих в свои творения желания"... И если во втором случае, как мне кажется, еще можно оставить и так, то уж в первом точно хочется что-то изменить. Кто-нибудь может посоветовать, как будет грамотно?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, **здесь в обоих лучше оставить В. п.** Такое решение  можно объяснить распространенностью дополнений, что придает им конкретный характер.

Сравнить: (1) **не испытывает желания** (устойчивое выражение с отвлеченным дополнением) и  (2) **не вкладывать** в свои творения **желание** (какое?) достичь новых показателей (также можно учесть дистантное положение дополнения).

Не допустить те ошибки, которые... - здесь также дополнение распространено придаточным предложением.

В то же время **использование Р. п. также возможно**, поэтому здесь уместно **авторское решение.**

Comment: Но ведь ошибки и желания "становятся" конкретными уже потом, после пояснения их сути! Не могу ещё как-то аргументировать, но мне винительный падеж тоже не нравится в обоих случаях.

Comment: Вообще говоря, Р.п. при отрицании является приоритетным, В.п. ослабляет отрицание,  и его использование должно как-то объясняться. Поэтому Р.п. здесь также вполне уместен, при исправлении падежа можно сослаться на книжный  (точный) стиль Р.п. и его подчеркнутое отрицание, в отличие от разговорного  характера  В.п.

Comment: Вот! Я тоже тяготею к родительному... Иначе мне что-то "режет" и глаз, и слух...